# Cant get Jquery ui autocomplete widget to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im trying to develop my first ASP.NET MVC web app and have run into a problem with the jquery ui autocomplete widget.

At the moment I have a form with a number of text boxs which would lend themselves well to an autocomplete ability.

The code for my "Make"(Car make) text box is show below:

jquery:

```
$(function() {
     $("#Make").autocomplete({
          source: '<%=Url.Action("Make","AutoComplete") %>' 
     });
});
```

ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Make(string term)
{
    return Json(Service.GetHints(HintType.Make, term, 20));
}
```

`GetHints()` returns an IList of Hints, an object with just label and value string properties. The documentation implies that this is what I should be returning to the jquery but it doesnt want to work? Can anyone give me any advice/help?

Comment: Are you successfully calling the ActionResult?

Comment: Yes. Its hitting the ActionResult everytime i edit the text in the Make textbox.

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation for the jQuery auto-complete widget that you are using? You may be returning your json data in the wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem too. You will need to change your ActionResult to JsonResult

There has been a change to JsonResult in MVC 2 and therefore it will no longer work with HTTP GET to avoid JSON hijacking.

So you could either change your code to return via HTTP POST or allow GET behaviour which may leave you open to [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).

Try modifying your code to follow the format

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

so your code will look like

```
public JsonResult Make(string term)
{
    return Json(Service.GetHints(HintType.Make, term, 20), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```